# Need php code to check that 2 users can't log on using the same phone

Tags: php

We are having a problem. We are working on a time registration homepage using php, where the users are logging in using an android phone.

We need some advice on how to code the login part.

The homepage should accept one Unique telephone. When that telephone communicates with the homepage, it should know who the user is.

We need the code to check that one telephone only belongs to one man. By that I mean that two people must not be able to use the same phone to login.

The solution also need to be secure, so it is not possible to access the data without legal access rights.

Does any of you have any idears ?

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: send verification code and activate application on last verified device with phone number.. exactly what whatsapp is doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IMEI` number of the phone to link the phone to a registered user account. For this you can create an app (`phonegap` would be easy for example) where the user registers the phone using the app (effectively linking the `IMEI` number to the `userid` in the database) by logging in.

You can then implement some logic to check if the `IMEI` number is already in use.

Hope that helps, the question is really broad though and it can be achieved in many different ways.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but this is what i think you should do.

Send the user's phone number to backend on app open/start, store that in local storage and also in database (if you have any). Delete the local storage on app exit. To make subsequent request to the server for that user you will have to set the authorization header for that user.

Answer (score 0):

For every device there is a unique Device id known as " device uuid ". If you are developing your application using phonegap or cordova you can easily use this [plugin](https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID) to get the unique device id, at the time of registration pass this unique device id to the database along with other registration entries and when the users logs in check his credentials with respect to this registered unique device id.